# Do Loop SAS, match and sum

Tags: sas

I have a dataset organized into households, and I have two variables which tell me who the person's mother or father is in the household, but there is no variable that tells me how many children each person has in the household, so I need to create the variable. I think I would use a do loop, but I am not sure how to SUM how many children points to that single individual as a parent.

Sample of data:

```
| serial | sex | age | personid | motherid | fatherid |
-------------------------------------------------------
|    111 |   1 |  34 |        1 |        . |        . |
|    111 |   2 |  33 |        2 |        . |        . |
|    111 |   2 |   2 |        3 |        2 |        1 |
|    111 |   2 |   4 |        4 |        2 |        1 |
|    105 |   1 |  56 |        1 |        . |        . |
|    105 |   2 |  49 |        2 |        . |        . |
|    105 |   1 |  15 |        3 |        2 |        1 |
```

So I want to create a variable **numkids** (number of kids) which for person 1 and 2 of household 111 would be 2 (within the household, two children pointed to them as their father and mother respectively) and for persons 1 and 2 in household 105 would be 1 (one child).

So far i've only been able to write something that shows that person 1 and 2 of both household has kids (binary, 0 for no kids at all and 1 for at least 1 kid), but not that they have TWO kids and ONE kid respectively. Would I have to use a SUM function here? I am not sure how that works.

This is the code I have:

```
data fam2; 
set fam1;
do i = 1 to nobs;
set fam1 (keep=serial motherid fatherid sex age 
             rename=(serial=serial1 motherid=motherid1 fatherid=fatherid1 sex=sex1 age=age1))
             point=i nobs=nobs;
if serial=serial1 and (personid=motherid1 or personid=fatherid1) 
then kid=1;
end;
drop serial1 motherid1 fatherid1 sex1 age1;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use PROC SQL:

```
data test;
    input serial sex age personid motherid fatherid;
    datalines;
111 1   34  1   .   .
111 2   33  2   .   .
111 2   2   3   2   1
111 2   4   4   2   1
105 1   56  1   .   .
105 2   49  2   .   .
105 1   15  3   2   1
;
run;

proc sql;
    create table test2 as
    select serial, motherid as personid, N(motherid) as numkids
    from test
    where motherid
    group by serial, motherid
    union all
    select serial, fatherid as personid, N(motherid) as numkids
    from test
    where fatherid
    group by serial, fatherid;

    create table test3 as
    select a.*, b.numkids
    from test as a
    left join test2 as b on a.serial=b.serial and a.personid=b.personid;
quit;

proc print data=test3; run;
```

Answer (score 0):

here's another way using proc sort and a data step:

```
proc sort data=test;
by  _serial desending _motherid;
run;

data test2;
set test;
by  _serial;
retain cnt;
if  first._serial then cnt = 0;
if _motherid not = . then cnt = cnt + 1;
run;

proc sort data=test2;
by descending _serial _motherid;
run;

data test3;
drop cnt ;
set test2;
retain temp;
if _motherid = . then numkids=cnt; 
else
numkids = .;
run;
```